# Shooting Method in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following equations in *Mathematica* 10

$$\frac { { d }^{ 3 }f }{ { d\eta  }^{ 3 } } +3\, f \frac { { d }^{ 2 }f }{ { d\eta  }^{ 2 } } -2{ \left( \frac { df }{ d\eta  }  \right)  }^{ 2 }+\theta = 0$$
and 
$$\frac { { d }^{2  }\theta}{ { d\eta  }^{ 2 } } +3.Pr.f\frac { { d \theta}}{ { d\eta  } }  =0$$
I wrote the following ODE in *Mathematica* but its not working giving error..kindly see if any one can sort it out.

```
system[Ω1_, Ω2_] := {
  f'[η] ==  g[η], 
  g'[η] == h[η], 
  h'[η] == -(3 f[η] g'[η] + 2 g[η]^2 + θ[η]),
  θ'[η] == a[η], 
  a'[η] == b[η], 
  b'[η] == -3 f[η] a[η], 
  f[0] == 0, 
  g[0] == 0, 
  θ[0] == 1, 
  g'[0] == Ω1, 
  a[0] == Ω2
}
myODEsoln[Ω1_, Ω2_] := NDSolve[system[Ω1, Ω2], {f, θ}, {η, 0, 10}]

yend[Ω1_?NumericQ, Ω2_?NumericQ] :={
  (First[f[η] /. myODEsoln[Ω1, Ω2]] /. η -> 10), 
  (First[θ[η] /. myODEsoln[Ω1, Ω2]] /. η -> 10)
}

yend[0.6, -0.5]

initVals = FindRoot[yend[α, β], {α, -0.5, -0.5}, {β, -0.5, -0.5}]

BVPsoln = myODEsoln[α /. initVals, β /. initVals, 1, -2]
```

The problem here is i am not getting the value.of f"[ 0] and θ'[0] under my initial assumptions of 0.6 and -0.5 and also you are right there are follwing boundary conditions...f[0]=0...f'[0]=0..f'[10]=0...θ[0]=1...θ[10]=0....and i am trying to determine Values of f''[0] and θ'[0

Comment: I am curious to know what physics this is capturing.  Looks like Falkner-Skan... boundary layer phenomenon?  Have you tried [NDSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html#659822336). I realize this isn't what you may have asked but as a lover of NDSolve... I just had to suggest that.

Comment: You added: "...there are follwing boundary conditions...f[0]=0...f'[0]=0..f'[10]=0...θ[0]=1...θ[10]=0...." -- that's still only 5 conditions for a system that needs 6. Don't you get an error that tells you that (`NDSolve::ndnco`)?

Answer (score 13):

You're missing a boundary condition (6 DEs, 5 BCs).  If I add a random one, say `a[0] == 1`, `NDSolve` can solve the system with the built-in shooting method.

```
system = {
     (* six DEs *)
   f'[η] == g[η],
   g'[η] == h[η],
   h'[η] == -(3 f[η] g'[η] + 2 g[η]^2 + θ[η]),
   θ'[η] == a[η],
   a'[η] == b[η],
   b'[η] == -3 f[η] a[η],
     (* five BCS *)
   f[0] == 0, g[0] == 0, θ[0] == 1, f[10] == 0, θ[10] == 0,
     (* extra BC *)
   a[0] == 1};

sol = NDSolve[system, {f, θ}, {η, 0, 10}];

Plot @@ {Through[{f, θ}[n]] /. sol, Flatten@{n, f["Domain"] /. sol}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It might be profitable to inform the OP that there really is no need to write everything in terms of first order derivatives; `NDSolve[]` has enough smarts to deal with things like `f'''[η] == -(3 f[η] f''[η] + 2 f'[η]^2 + θ[η])`.